# Dependency management of outputted UMD files

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack, umd, react-spinners

I'm looking to take [an NPM package](https://github.com/davidhu2000/react-spinners) and output it as UMD so it can be used directly in browser, via a script tag or SystemJS import.

The issue I have is that the NPM package is a react-component library, meaning it has dependencies on react and react-dom. The package itself marks both react and react-dom as peer dependencies.

If I update webpack.config.js with

```
externals: ['react-spinners']
```

and load the umd file via a script tag

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-spinners@0.12.0-alpha.1/umd/index.js"></script>
```

I get an error say

> ReferenceError: react is not defined

Is there a way to use `tsc` to output a UMD module and specify certain dependencies are necessary? something along the lines of

```
tsc --project tsconfig.umd.json --outDir umd --addDeps react,react-dom
```

so that when this package is loaded, it'll check both react and react-dom exist first before executing?

```
      <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@17.0.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17.0.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-spinners@0.12.0-alpha.1/umd/index.js"></script>
```

i tried something like this but still received the same react error

build command

```json
"build:umd": "tsc --project tsconfig.umd.json --outDir umd"
```

tsconfig

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "alwaysStrict": true,
    "sourceMap": false,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "strictFunctionTypes": true,
    "strictPropertyInitialization": true,
    "strictBindCallApply": true,
    "module": "umd",
    "jsx": "react",
    "target": "es5",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "lib": ["dom", "es2017", "es5", "es6", "es7"],
    "outDir": ".",
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true
  },
  "exclude": ["docs/*", "webpack.config.*", "*.js", "__tests__", "examples"]
}
```

peer deps

```
  "peerDependencies": {
    "react": "^16.0.0 || ^17.0.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.0.0 || ^17.0.0"
  },
```